# How I can retrieve image from database into datagrid in WPF with EF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, datagrid

I'm new in Entity framework so I need help. I saved image to database (SQL Server) and then I want to retrieve the image into a datagrid
here is my code:

```
using(var contxt=new lotteryEntities1())
        {
            var AllPlayer = contxt.GetAllPlayars();
            foreach( var pp in AllPlayer)
            {

                string PName = pp.Player_name;
                string phone = pp.Player_Phone;
                 Photos = ToImage(pp.Photo);
            }

            //DTGridEmp.ItemsSource = pp;
        }
```

And here is my Xaml code:

```
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Image">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Photos}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

I'm calling the procedure from my entity and need to bind all columns into data grid with image?

Comment: *any help* for what? You didn't asked any question!

Comment: this is my code i'm try to retrieve  image in database into datagride

Comment: Well ? What's your problem? You need to be more specific about your problem.

Comment: The problem is the image not appear in data gride

Comment: Of course nobody needs to know what `Photos = ToImage(pp.Photo); ` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the answer

```
   List<Players> player = new List<Players>();

        using (var contxt = new lotteryEntities1())
        {

            var AllPlayer = contxt.GetAllPlayars();

            foreach(var pp in AllPlayer)
            {
                player.Add(new Players() { PalyerName = pp.Player_name, PlayerPhone = pp.Player_Phone,Pics=pp.Photo});
            }
            DTGridEmp.ItemsSource = player;


            //  DTGridEmp.ItemsSource = items;

        }
```

And the Xaml code is

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DTGridEmp"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,13,0,0" Width="Auto" Height="Auto"  Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}" ColumnHeaderHeight="40"  FlowDirection="RightToLeft" SelectedIndex="0"   ColumnWidth=" 243" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionChanged="DTGridEmp_SelectionChanged" PreviewMouseDown="DTGridEmp_PreviewMouseDown">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding PalyerName}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="TelePhone" Binding="{Binding PlayerPhone}"  />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Photo" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Pics}" Width="40" Height="40" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Thanks for all